# ViewEncapsulation.None creates conflict in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to customize CSS styles in two components that use another component that wraps a javascript editor (CodeMirror).

The component is called `editor`, and I use it like so:

```
<editor [someVal]="123"></editor>
```

To adjust the editor height I use `styles` in the first Angular component:

```
styles: [`
        .CodeMirror-scroll{
            max-height: 120px !important;
        }
`],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

I need to use `ViewEncapsulation.None` otherwise the style is not applied to the editor.

I do the same in the second Angular component, but with a different `height`:

```
styles: [`
        .CodeMirror-scroll{
            max-height: 500px !important;
        }
`],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Problem is that there's a conflict when I have both styles in effect in the application. It always takes the height of the second component. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be more specific with the CSS in what component should apply what CSS.

```
my-component-1 .CodeMirror-scroll{
  max-height: 120px !important;
}
my-component-2 .CodeMirror-scroll{
  max-height: 500px !important;
}
```

Or you can apply different classes that encapsulate the component(s) using that CodeMirror-scroll.

```
.CodeMirror-scroll{
  max-height: 120px !important;
}
.larger .CodeMirror-scroll{
  max-height: 500px !important;
}
```

Comment: where do I define `my-component-1` and `my-component-2` ?

Comment: Those are the selector names of your components

Comment: I used your first option, in one of them works and in the second it doesn't. Both components are very similar, any idea what could be happening? Is this issue related to styles or probably something else? I accepted your answer because this is probably a different issue, but what should I check?

Comment: I think I need more information about the setup. If you would be willing to do a simple reproduction in StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/ I'd be happy to help more!

Comment: I found it, it was something else not related to styles, thanks.